# GraphQL Error: Required param is missing in invocation

Tags: graphql, mulesoft

I am using Mulesoft DataGraph to create a graphql endpoint. When running the below test graphql query, I get the following error:

Query:

`{newmover{AGE}}`

Error:

`"Exception while fetching data (/newmover[0]/AGE) : Required param VKEY is missing in invocation"`

I double checked the RAML and the endpoint this query uses does not require a parameter.